# How to add string variable to sh script in Jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, sh, jenkins-groovy

I am new to jenkins and the syntax and I am having problem adding a variable containing string with spaces to the shell script.

```
def key = "12345678"
def notes = "My release notes"

sh "./scripts.sh appcenter distribute release --token ${key} --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes \"${notes}\" --debug"
```

The problem is on the `notes` variable, I am not able to get it to quoted properly.  I have tried using `\'`, `\"`, `\\\"`, and tried without escape `'`, and all throwing error because it's not treating `notes` as one quoted string and try to execute what is inside the string instead.

How can I add the variable and have it quoted properly for the script to run correctly?

Edit:
In `scripts.sh` I basically have a setup like this:

```
install)
  npm install -g appcenter-cli
  ;;
appcenter)
  appcenter ${@:2}
  ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use shell block (`sh """` just to avoid this sort of issues as `\` escapes tend to get lost in Groovy and shell escape loops. Here's a sample Pipeline I used to test it out; since I don't know what's inside your `scripts.sh` script, I simply echo back what I passed in.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
      label 'jenkins-node'
  }

  options {
    timestamps()
  }
  
  stages {
      
    stage('File'){
        steps {
            sh """
            echo 'echo \$@' > scripts.sh
            """
        }
    }

    stage('Test'){

      steps {
              script {
                def key = "12345678"
                def notes = "My release notes"
                sh """
                cat ./scripts.sh
                sh ./scripts.sh  appcenter distribute release --token ${key} --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes "${notes}" --debug
                """
              }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Output

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (File)
[Pipeline] sh
22:33:52  + echo echo $@
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
22:33:52  + cat ./scripts.sh
22:33:52  echo $@
22:33:52  + sh ./scripts.sh appcenter distribute release --token 12345678 --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes My release notes --debug
22:33:52  appcenter distribute release --token 12345678 --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes My release notes --debug
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

---

## Update

```
....

    stage('Test'){
      steps {
              script {
                def key = "12345678"
                def notes = 'My release notes'
                sh """
                set -x
                cat ./scripts.sh
                sh ./scripts.sh appcenter distribute release --token ${key} --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes '\"${notes}\"' --debug
                """
              }
      }
    }
    
...
```

> Output

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timestamps
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (File)
[Pipeline] sh
12:27:48  + echo echo $@
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
12:27:49  + set -x
12:27:49  + cat ./scripts.sh
12:27:49  echo $@
12:27:49  + sh ./scripts.sh appcenter distribute release --token 12345678 --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes "My release notes" --debug
12:27:49  appcenter distribute release --token 12345678 --app MyApp/Test --file myapp.apk --release-notes "My release notes" --debug
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  In my `scripts.sh` I basically have the `npm install -g appcenter-cli` in order to use appcenter commands and `appcenter) appcenter ${@:2} ;;` to execute the commands.  Anyway, looking at your output, it still didn't have quotes on the notes: `--release-notes My release notes`.  What I need is `--release-notes "My release notes"`

Comment: If you want the actual `\"` to be there you need to pass them in as literal characters. I've added an update to show thet changes. Sorry took so long to get back

Answer (score 0):

Here this will work:

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                
                script {
                def key = "12345678"
                def notes = "\"My release notes\""
                
                
                echo "${notes}"
                
                echo "The new notes name is: ${notes}"
            }
            
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried your way, but somehow when executed `sh` commands, it still throws me the error `failed with exception "Unknown arguments: release notes"` as if the quotes in the notes got dropped or ignored.  Weird.  The command with the quotes around the notes works correctly if I execute the command directly in a bash terminal.